# Where can I get trained in Speech?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to increase my speech skill in Skyrim so that I can sell any item to any merchant.
Where can I find someone who will train me in the Speech skill?

Comment: Related: [What is the fastest way to level up my speech skill?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43560/4797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many places all over the world of Skyrim where you can be taught speech.

Information about speech can be found on the wiki [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Speech).

One of the methods of gaining speech as written on the wiki:

> **Method Two**
>
> During the Dark Brotherhood quest, "Recipe for Disaster", Anton Virane (the Chef of the Understone Keep in Markarth) can be intimidated repeatedly to level Speech. This can be accomplished by:
>
> - When talking with him, after saying "For the Dark Brotherhood, that can be easily arranged. (Intimidate)", he will respond "The Dark Brotherhood?".
> - If the conversation is immediately exited, the Dragonborn can begin to talk to him again and quickly skip through most of the conversation.
> - Exiting the conversation at the same time as before increases Speech.
>   This can be repeated forever.

Check that wiki page though, too much to explain here, it shows EVERYTHING on it.

**Speech Trainers**

Adept --- Dro'marash --- Khajiit Caravans (Travels between Riften and Dawnstar)
Adept --- Revyn Sadri --- Sadri's Used Wares in Windhelm
Adept --- Ronthil --- Castle Volkihar **(Only available with The Elder Scrolls V: Dawnguard)**
Expert --- Ogmund --- Markarth  (Can be found in the Silver-Blood Inn)
Master --- Giraud Gemane --- Bards College in Solitude

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Revyn Sadri's a common trainer(to lvl 50). He's a general goods merchant, so will buy anything. Handy if you're leveling crafting skills and looking for somewhere to sell the debris. You will need to do a small task for him first before he'll train you. You need to covertly return a ring to its owner's house(master locked. Best to make a save and try pickpocketing the key from the owner. Reload and try again if you get caught, but since keys weigh nothing and are worth nothing you shouldn't have much trouble). After that, you can pay for training and get even more xp in sales to get gold back.